# How can my application retrieve custom fields from a DocuSign transaction?

Tags: docusignapi

I am working with DocuSign custom fields. I want to get all my custom fields that were created in the admin console by using a REST API call.

Is there any REST call to get all the custom fields?

Comment: Your question is not very clear so I'm not sure exactly what you're asking.  When you say you want to "get all the custom fields" what do you mean?  Do you mean if you send a signature request (envelope) that has custom fields on it, you would like to retrieve the VALUES of your custom fields once it's completed?  Or are you looking to download all the custom fields you've setup in your account?  Or something else?

Comment: hi sorry for late reply . i have created some custom fields in admin console.for ex(text tab sign tab). i want to get all the custom fields that were created by me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not get all custom fields of Account through Docusign API V2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782112/could-not-get-all-custom-fields-of-account-through-docusign-api-v2)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're wanting the information that you've set up displayed in JSON via REST.

endpoint: GET https://{server}/restapi/v2/accounts/{accountId}/custom_fields

This will return your `textCustomFields` and `listCustomFields`

Comment: I have setup sandbox account and using this endpoint, it does not return the custom field I have created in Admin section. Can you guess what is wrong here?

Comment: Envelope Custom Fields and Document Custom Fields are two different things. You may be filling out one in admin and searching for the other. Are you trying to place a custom tab to have the user interact with? Or are you trying to apply a label to the envelope to track off of later?

Comment: I have posted here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40782112/could-not-get-all-custom-fields-of-account-through-docusign-api-v2/40787886#40787886