# Could not get all custom fields of Account through Docusign API V2

Tags: api, docusignapi

I have setup following custom fields in sandbox environment. When I use following API, it do not return this custom field. Can someone guide here what is wrong with API call.

> GET
>   https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/2055851/custom_fields
>   HTTP/1.1

---

Getting following response:

```
HTTP/1.1
date: Thu, 24 Nov 2016 09
X-Frame-Options: Deny
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
x-ratelimit-remaining: 999
cache-control: no-cache
x-ratelimit-reset: 1479981600
x-ratelimit-limit: 1000
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Content-Length: 57
{
    "textCustomFields": [],
    "listCustomFields": []
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the naming confusion.

You created "Custom Tabs" from the point of view of the API. Use the [CustomTabs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/CustomTabs/CustomTabs/) resource to get/list/create/update/delete them programmatically.

**Added**

There are also [Account Custom Fields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/CustomFields/) at the account level. They're read-only

And there are [Envelope Custom Fields](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeCustomFields/) too. They're useful for adding/storing additional information about an envelope.

You can search an account for envelopes with specific Envelope Custom Field content via the [Envelopes: listStatusChanges](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listStatusChanges/) method using its `custom_field` query parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. So what do you mean by custom fields for the account rather than envelope. And from where I can set them up in UI.

Comment: @ManishPansiniya Thank you for the check! I've updated my answer with more info on Custom Fields